# UITableView data source update issue

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitableview

I have UITableView which has edit button in all rows with tag as id of the data in corresponding row.In the first row i have button to insert new item when i click on button on first row to add new item,navigates to insert form,add data to database in that forms n bring back to original uitableview which i reload in viewDidAppear.New Item along with button can be seen in the table n also i can view  (in my logs ofcourse ) my NSMutableArray  get updated with new data n button with appropriate tag (i.e with new ID) ;which i have provided as data source to uitableview; while binding data.
Now But when i tried to edit my newly added item i got correct ID for my  Data at the button tag which is clicked, but surprisingly ,now , same array which i have observed being updated while binding,has short of new data in array but surprisngly visible on uitableview
y is it so ????

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried [yourTable reloadData]; ?

Comment: yes i have called it in viewDidAppear n which is workin fine as i have printed on console my datasource array numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath also new data can be seen in uitableview also tag holds appropriate IDs